# No CMS page assigned for this CMS

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

I have been recieving this error on the clients MAC machne in Safari Browser 
Its working fine everywhere else in other browsers Any guesses on this Issue.

Thanks

Comment: You need to add more information on what you are talking about. Where exactly are you getting the message, in what context?

Comment: in the content section It is showing up the header but footer an the home page is missing i m getting the message in the content section

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not elaborated enough as @Pekka said one thing comes to mind.

You should probably check if a CMS page you're trying to reach exists (for example the Home Page) and if it is enabled. Go to: CMS -> Pages and select the page from the list in there.

Hope this sheds some light.